# How can I add an Adornment or a ToolTip to a temporaryToPort Object of (Re-)LinkingTool on dragging links

Tags: gojs

When re-/Linking nodes in GoJs, I need specialized information (as a ToolTip, adornment or similar) about the currently temporary selected port of a node (e.g. port name or type etc.) when Mouse hovers it.
A simple toolTip on the appropriate Panel/Shape definition doesn't work when dragging links.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to customize the **LinkingTool**. For example, see:
https://gojs.net/extras/linkValidationToolTip.html

Comment: As far I understand, the example will show an ToolTip only on a Node, not for a specialized/dedicated port which is defined by a shape inside a node.

Comment: That sample has Nodes that only have one port each.  If your nodes have multiple ports, you can adapt that code to show a ToolTip per port or any other object that you choose.